# Do custom web-site cookie approvals override Firefox defaults re third-party cookies?

Tags: firefox, cookie

I am running up to date Firefox version, and have the browser cookie settings set to disallow third-party cookies.

Often, when browsing a web-site, I am asked by the site to allow cookies. This is usually a pre-requisite to continuing, so often have little choice.

I would like to know if these custom cookie approvals override the Firefox default setting that I have set?  Which take precedence?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Firefox provides the facility to inspect local storage, including cookies:
Menu Bar>Tools>Web Developer>Storage Inspector

The Storage Inspector shows cookies loaded for the current web-page (with some limitation) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Storage_Inspector

On reviewing pages loaded when in private browsing mode, only original source (first party) cookies seem to be loaded, even though "I accept" manual approval was provided to the web-page for all its related cookies.